# how to fix this combined arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays I want to combine them together first array

`$array1[]=(11,12,3,9);`

and second array

`$array2[]=(mikel,joe,sami,toni);`

I need the combined array like that

```
$combined_array[]=(Mikel,11,joe,12,sami,3,toni,9);
```

I tried this code in PHP but didn't work

```
$array1[]=(11,12,3,9);
$array2[]=(mikel,joe,sami,toni);
for( $i=0;$i<sizeof($array1); $i++){
    $combined= array();
    $a = $array1[$i];
    $b= $array2[$i];
    array_push($combined,$a,$b);
}
```

Comment: How are Laravel and CodeIgniter related to the question?

Comment: What is wrong with using `array_merge`?

Comment: array_merge will merge them in different index order

Answer (score 4):

```
$array1[]=(11,12,3,9);
$array2[]=(mikel,joe,sami,toni);
 $combined= array();

for( $i=0;$i<sizeof($array1); $i++){
    $a = $array1[$i];
    $b= $array2[$i];
    array_push($combined,$a,$b);
}
```

EDIT:
Declare your $combine array before for loop

Comment: You should use `count` instead, size_of is just an alias

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = array(11, 12, 3, 9);
$array2 = array('mikel', 'joe', 'sami', 'toni');
$combined = array();

for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($array1); $i++) {
    array_push($combined, $array2[$i], $array1[$i]);
}

print_r($combined);
```

Answer (score 0):

just you must replace `array_push($combined, $a, $b)` to 2 line code :

```
array_push($combined, $a)
```

and

```
array_push($combined, $b)
```

also you could replace `sizeof($array1)` in your `forloop` to `count($array1) - 1`

will be ok